# How to get smoother transition between the surface normals rotation of player in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, movement, normals

I kinda have a problem that my player is snapping onto the other surface while I wanna move a ramp up. I want to have it rotate smooth to the normals of the ramp. How can I change the code below to a smoother rotation function of the player?

Code:

---

```
void NormalsOfGround()
{
    //RAYCASTS THE NORMALS ON THE GROUND THAT THE PLAYER MOVES ALONG SURFACE
    Debug.DrawRay(rayCastNormal.transform.position, -transform.up, Color.blue, 2.5f);
    Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, -transform.up);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2.5f, GroundLayer) == true)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate by a controlled number of degrees each frame with:

[Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)(from, to, maxDegreesDelta)

So your code can look something like this:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2.5f, GroundLayer)) {

    var targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (
                 transform.up,
                 hit.normal
             ) * transform.rotation;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
                transform.rotation,
                targetRotation,
                degreePerSecondSpeed * Time.deltaTime
             );
}
```

Comment: "Kinda" suggest there are some in-game results you might like to see improved? Lay it on us and I or another user here can try to help. :)